# Freenas/FreeBSD Mapping IPv6 to IPv4

Tags: ipv6, freebsd, ipv4, plex

I have an Plexmediaserver in a Freenas Jail, which I can acess with an IPv4 adress on a specific port. 
But I also need to acess it with IPv6.

I need a portmapper or something like this.
For Windows i found the following:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v6tov4 32400 192.168.1.35 32400
```

And it works.

I need something like this on my Freenas(FreeBSD) Server, but i can't figure out how.

Edit:
I have ipfw installed now. I need something like:

```
ipfw -q add fwd 192.168.1.35,32400 all from any to any 32400 in
```

but it won't work like this

Answer (score 0):

In FreeBSD jails [IPv6](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-ipv6.html) and IPv4 works very nice together, this is just a very basic example `/etc/jail.conf` of how to do it

```
exec.start = "/bin/sh /etc/rc";
exec.stop = "/bin/sh /etc/rc.shutdown";
exec.clean;
mount.devfs;
allow.raw_sockets;
securelevel=3;
host.hostname="$name.your-hostname";
path="/tank/jails/$name";

base {
    jid = 10;
    ip6.addr = bge0|2001:4860:4860:0063::3;
    ip4.addr = 192.168.1.35;
}
```

In this case, `bge0` is the interface containing the ipv6 segment `/64`

You will need to set the [IP alias](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/freebsd-how-to-setup-2-ip-address-on-one-nic.html) on your main host and in most cases no need to do NAT.